# Wordpress wrong update suggestion for plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I have made a custom plugin in Wordpress that makes a custom post-type for banners.

The problem is that Wordpress suggests an update for the plugin, and the update is a completely different plugin from mine **but** it's also a banner-plugin.

This is my code:

```
/*
Plugin Name:  Test banner

Description:  This is a test banner plugin

Version:      1.0

*/

add_action('init', function() {

    $rw_one = "Banner";
    $rw_two = "Banners";

    $rw_one_lc = strtolower($rw_one);
    $rw_two_lc = strtolower($rw_two);

    register_post_type('rw-banner', array(

        'public'    => true,
        'show_ui'   => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-slides',
        'label'     => 'Slideshow',
        'labels'    => array(
                           'name'                   => $rw_one,
                           'singular_name'          => $rw_one,
                           'add_name'               => "Add new",
                           'add_new_item'           => "Add new {$rw_one_lc}",
                           'add_new'                => "Add new",
                           'edit_item'              => "Adjust {$rw_one_lc}",
                           'new_item'               => "new {$rw_one_lc}",
                           'view_item'              => "See {$rw_one_lc}",
                           'search_item'            => "Search in {$rw_two_lc}",
                           'not_found'              => "No {$rw_two_lc} found",
                           'not_found_in_trash'     => "No {$rw_two_lc} found in trash",
                           'parent_item_colon'      => "Parent {$rw_one_lc}",
                           'all_items'              => "All {$rw_two_lc}",
                           'archives'               => "{$rw_one} archives",
                           'insert_into_item'       => "Insert into {$rw_one_lc}",
                           'uploaded_to_this_item'  => "Uploaded to {$rw_one_lc}"
                       ),
        'supports'  => array(
                            'title',
                            'thumbnail'
                        )


    ));

});
```

- As you see, this is a very simply plugin. I have even tried making a new plugin from scratch, where the names are switched from 'banner' to slideshow, and then Wordpress just finds a another update that has something to do with a slideshow.
- I have also tried prefixing the folders and files and post-type for many different thing, and after updating the browser one or two times, it finds another update yet again!
- I have even tried making it all from scratch on a whole new Wordpress installation, and on a completely different domain, but still it suggests an update!

I hope some of you can help me with this.

NOTE: This is only happening when I make a plugin for a post-type, my other plugins are fine.

OTHER NOTE: If I edit the version to some something like 9.9 it removes the suggested updates, but this just doesn't seem like a real solution.

Comment: probably it is too much coincidence with other plugin, try to set a really unique name to your plugin for example the folder name of the plugin "rasmus-banner-slideshow-different" and your main file with the same name of the folder "rasmus-banner-slideshow-different.php"

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm having the same problem, but the names of my folder *and* php file already start with "ginchens-..." You'd think that was unique enough... :/